# conda install basemap in python2.7 environment gives Runtime error R6034

Tags: python, anaconda

This is my first post here, so if I need to give more info, could you ask me?

I installed Anaconda 2018.12 python 3.7 version, adding anaconda to my path environment variable. I made a new environment with "create -n py2.7 python=2.7 anaconda", and installing netcdf4 (conda install -c conda-forge netcdf4) and basemap(conda install -c conda-forge basemap) in the new environment.

However, soon after installing basemap, the command prompt gave Runtime error R6034. Then, the error started to repeat happening even when I just tried "conda list" in the new environment. The base environment seems working fine.

Could anyone help me to solve this issue? I cannot open even spyder in this situation either from start menu or command prompt.

Version: windows10, anaconda 2018-12

The following was what I tried to solve the issue, so far.

1. I re-installed anaconda multiple times, but it did not work.
2. Using "Process Explorer" and found msvcr90.dll in folders relating to the python process. Then, changing the name to msvcr90.dll_hihi. I found this way in Youtube, but gave another error: CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 Connection Failed.
3. I re-installed without adding anaconda to my path environmental variable. However, this did not work, either.

I am totally confused and so depressed not to be able to use anaconda for my research. I really appreciate it if anyone could help me.

Comment: I installed same Anaconda on Windows and also created 2.7 env. The same R6034 error dialog pops up when you "deactivate" the 2.7 env.

Comment: Just now removed Anaconda3, then installed Anaconda2 (2.7, 2018-12, 64 bit). Then created a 3.7 env. I also installed to C:\Anaconda2, in case long path with spaces was a problem. No problems seen; no R6034 error.

Comment: Thank you for your information, Glenn! Your way is working!! I appreciate it!

Comment: I get the same R6034 error after installing `requests` (2.21.0) in a clean python 2.7.15 environment, using a freshly installed Miniconda 3 64bit on Windows 10.

Comment: Traced it back to `openssl` (1.1.1b) which is installed as a dependency of `requests`.

Comment: I got R6034 when opening a project in PyCharm with an Anaconda environment i setup for 2.7. Turns out it was openSSL 1.1.1d which was part of this env. I removed it and error is gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem with Anaconda3 and Python27. I solved this problem via executing the following command in cmd, outside of any conda environment:

```
conda install msvc_runtime
```

After installing the packages, open a new command and test if the R6034 error still appears.

Comment: What do you mean 'outside of any conda'? Does it mean executing in the base environment? Thank you for your comment, Huanfa!

Comment: @U.T Yes. I corrected my answer - outside of any conda env. So the change is made to the base environment.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification!